# Only one of two Tooltipster hovers show up in IE9

Tags: jquery, tooltipster

I'm using the Tooltipster plugin on my Boostrap site. I have tooltips in two different spots right next to each other on the page. When testing locally and through emailonacid.com, both tooltips show up as expected. However, in IE9/IE8, only the one on the right shows up. The one on the left has seemingly disappeared.

I've looked through the official Tooltipster FAQ and forums, and previous versions seemed to have issues in IE9, but apparently no longer. I'm stumped. Here's a jsfiddle (my apologies if it's not enough info, I've never used it before):

https://jsfiddle.net/st7zx58r/

Thanks for any help you can provide!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
   animation : 'grow',
  content: $('<span><strong>Includes:</strong><br />&bull; Online Ads<br />&bull; Online Trade Publications<br />&bull; Social Media Advertising<br />&bull; Email Blasts<br />&bull; Print Publications<br />&bull; Direct Mailer<br />&bull; Web Videos<br />&bull; SEM/SEO<br />&bull; Other</span>'),
   contentAsHTML: true,
    interactive: true,
  });
});  
  

  

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tooltip2').tooltipster({
   animation : 'grow',
  content: $('<span><strong>TESTING:</strong><br />&bull; Online Ads<br />&bull; Online Trade Publications<br />&bull; Social Media Advertising<br />&bull; Email Blasts<br />&bull; Print Publications<br />&bull; Direct Mailer<br />&bull; Web Videos<br />&bull; SEM/SEO<br />&bull; Other</span>'),
   contentAsHTML: true,
    interactive: true,
  });
});
```

```css
.form-text {
 text-align: left;
 font-family: 'LincolnProximaNova-Bold', Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 17px;
 color: #53565a;
 margin-left:15px;


}

.radiobtn1 {
 text-align: left;
 font-family: 'LincolnProximaNova', Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #b45f1a;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;

}
.radiobtn1 a{
 text-align: left;
 font-family: 'LincolnProximaNova', Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #b45f1a;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}



.radiobtn1 ul{
 text-align:center;


}

.radiobtn1 li{
 list-style: none;
 display: inline;
 padding-left:30px; 

}
```

```html
<script src="http://designumber18.com/wedding/jquery.tooltipster.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row form-text">
  
    <p>Please select the category for this claim.</p>
    </div>
         
    <div class="row radiobtn1">
      <ul>
    <li><input type="radio" name="media"><label for="qualified">&nbsp;Advertising (Digital/Print)</label><span id="stayTool" class="tooltipstered"> <img src="images/question-mark.png" style="cursor: pointer;" class="tooltip" ></span></li>
    
    <li><input type="radio" name="media"><label for="qualified">&nbsp;Experiential Event</label><span id="stayTool" class="tooltipstered"> <img src="images/question-mark.png" style="cursor: pointer;" class="tooltip2" ></span></li>



      
      </ul>   
  
 </div>
```

Comment: The JSFiddle example is great; exactly what we need... except that doesn't work because you haven't included the tooltipster or jquery libraries.

Comment: Yeah, I figured I was missing something. :( Not sure how to include those... In the snippet, looks like I can add an external library, is that where I need to include the tooltipster.js file?